Can only a collection of photons create light with a direction?
I assume that any individual photon spreads in all direction of space, resembling a circular wave. So, a single photon cannot have a specific direction of travel. Consequently, light with a direction could only arise from the emission of multiple photons originating from distinct positions, resulting in the formation of a wavefront in one direction, while experiencing destructive interference in all others. Is this true?

Are you familiar with the plane wave? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave

I am aware of the mathematical description of plane waves. This question however is rather about the nature of photons.

This might help - How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?

This is interesting, but doesn't quite answer the question of the directionality

I don't quite understand the basis for your assumption. Whatever process creates the photon gives it direction.

As far as I’ve understood, the moment a single photon is created, it spreads as a (probability) wave in all directions. It is in a superposition of all locations. Only when the photon is measured, it becomes localized in space and time. Only then does the photon get a direction (i.e. the direction from source to detector)

photons are point elementary particles in the standard model of particle physics. A single photon is not a wave, it is described by a four vector and the momentum has a specific direction. may be my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284385/which-elementary-particles-does-light-interact-with/284436#284436 and here  will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210124/velocity-of-photon-when-changing-direction/210155#210155

Well, it is localized after the measurement, but before that it can only spread out as a circular wave. Here (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/87070/304220) it said, a single emitted photon "can be regarded as a a wave train of finite duration, spreading out in all directions in space". Thus, I would argue that only a collection of photons can form a wave package and is consequently localized to some extend at any point in time.
